# Monitoring what packages are called

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to work out what packages/functions are being called by an oracle form.
I have sysdba access to the database. Is there an easy way to determine this? I know of a very rough method (using the file writing package to write text files to the filesystem) but I'm sure there must be something a bit easier to monitor SQL's and what is being called?

I am using SQL Developer.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: see this [DBMS_PROFILER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_profil.htm) or this: [DBMS_HPROF](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_hprof.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This is my own session monitor query, take a look:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(program, 1, 15), SUBSTR(event, 1, 21), DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(WRH.sql_text, 100),
       (   TO_CHAR(FLOOR((SYSDATE - logon_time) * 24), 'FM000')
        || ':'
        || TO_CHAR(FLOOR(MOD((SYSDATE - logon_time) * 1440, 60)), 'FM00')
        || ':'
        || TO_CHAR(MOD((SYSDATE - logon_time) * 86400, 60), 'FM00'))
        "Elapsed Time", --WRS.cpu_cost,WRS.operation,WRS.options,WRS.position,WRS.search_columns,WRS.cost,WRS.bytes,WRS.TIME,
       schemaname, terminal, plsql_entry_object_id, osuser,
       process, username, MODULE, ROW_WAIT_OBJ#, "ROW_WAIT_FILE#", "ROW_WAIT_BLOCK#", sid,
       USER#, command, SCHEMA#, logon_time, blocking_session_status, "SEQ#", wait_class,
       state, service_name
  FROM V$SESSION SS, SYS.WRH$_SQLTEXT WRH                         --,SYS.WRH$_SQL_PLAN WRS
 WHERE WRH.sql_id = SS.sql_id
   --AND program LIKE 'f90runm@node%'
   --AND username NOT IN ('SYS', 'SYSMAN')
ORDER BY program
```

work with DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(WRH.sql_text, 100) to achieve better results in current activity.
I think you better use Sql navigator or Toad, because they have good session browser.